# ORA-01403 no data found error

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a simple select query which returns me data.

```
select COL_DES from MY_TABLE where COL_CODE = 'ABC';
```

But when I encapsulate this with in procedure and call it from my C# code, i get the ORA-01403 no data found error.
Here is what I am doing:

```
PROCEDURE GET_DESCRIPTION(
    type_code     IN   VARCHAR2,
    type_desc     OUT  VARCHAR2    
)
IS
BEGIN
    select COL_DES into type_desc
    from LOANIQ.MY_TABLE 
    where COL_CODE = type_code;
END;
```

And from the C# code, I do pass the type_code as 'ABC' but I do not get any results. Instead, I get an oracle error - ORA-01403 no data found error.

```
comm.Parameters.Add("type_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value ="ABC";
comm.Parameters.Add("type_desc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1024).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
comm.BindByName = true;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Kunal

Comment: when you run your SQL using SQL client against database, does it return any data? The error is thrown when you use SELECT INTO and no rows are returned from the query.

Comment: I had already tried that. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

It was a coding error on my part. The column "COL_CODE" was a type "CHAR" column and the parameter which was used for equating "type_code" was a "VARCHAR2".
Once I changed "type_code" to "CHAR" from code and the proc, it worked fine.

Thanks,
Kunal